# I cant read an xml file on blazor

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

As i said i cant read a local XML file.

Im using this path that is on my pc: "C:\Users\Autoescuela\Desktop\Models\models.xml"

```
        public Models SerializeModels(string path)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Models));
            Models? models;
            using (Stream reader = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                models = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Models;
            }

            return models;

        }
```

and this is the error :

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find file '/C:\Users\Autoescuela\Desktop\Models\models.xml'.

I tryed to put my folder Models on wwwroot folder, but i still having the same problem.

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find file '/~\Models\models.xml'

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find file '/Models\models.xml'.

I also need use this XML in other application that uses the same xml and update on both at the same time, but i if its needed to use on wwwroot isnt a problem.

Comment: You are building a Web App. There are no 'local files'.

Comment: Do not delete& repost. Improve your question instead.

Comment: then i cant work with my xml ?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to request the XML file from the backend, not from the file system.

Comment: I do not really know how to do that, have you an example ? and thanks.

Comment: Check the docs -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server has both Blazor Server and Blazor Web Assembly covered.

Comment: There was a full answer on the previous version of this question, what happened with that?

Comment: sorry @HenkHolterman for remove last question im new in Stack and i dont know how to work so much on this web , i removed last question bc it was really bad redacted and each answer was how much bad was redacted, then i decided to remove that bad question and redo a good one with some code, and i do not really remeber an answer im not sure if Stack didnt charched or i didnt saw, atleast im sorry for my bad movments on this web.

Comment: Create a new Wasm App (not Hosted) and look at how the forecast data is obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I take the data from the xml  like this

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{

    models = XqueryFunctions.GetModels(await http.GetStringAsync("Models/models.xml"));
}
```

and then I load with .loadXml()

```
    public static XmlNodeList Xquery(string xpath, string document)
    {

        XmlDocument xml = new();
        xml.LoadXml(document);
        return xml.SelectNodes(xpath);


    }
```

I know isnt a good aswer but it works, if some one can take the file instead of the file string I would really appreciate it.